# What are the steps to bootstrap encryption into an existing unencrypted consul cluster without downtime

Tags: encryption, consul

I have setup a consul cluster with 3 server nodes. The cluster in unencrypted.
Please let me know what steps do I need to follow to bootstrap encryption into the existing unencrypted cluster without downtime

Answer (score 0):

You can't enable Gossip encryption at runtime. Using `consul keyring` you can only *change* the gossip encryption key at runtime (the attempt results in the error message *No keyring to modify (encryption not enabled)*)

You can add TLS by first rolling out your certificates, and then enable the `verify*` options as outlined in [Consul's encryption docs](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/encryption.html).